# ipad Receiving Low Memory warning while Loading WebView with local HTML content and App crashes..!

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I am loading my webview with html contents containing a lot of pages. Its working perfectly in simulator and in device it displays low memory warning issue.
Plz join hands ...

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of memory management. You should provide your code ( both .h and .m ). It does not matter WHAT you do ( loading content in webwiew or whatever ), it matters THE WAY you do that. You probably are not releasing the unnecessary objects, or you are allocating too much memory. In simulator is ok, it uses computer's memory. Review your code, release or nil unused objects. Try the Profiler to detect memory leaks. Cheers!